# Deducting the total leave when the leave request is approved

Tags: php, laravel

I have column total leave in table user and column days taken and status in table leave. I tried to deduct the total leave with the leave days taken when the leave is approved but it is not updated. I've tried with this code.

This function is for the applicant to apply for leave.

```
public function store(Request $request){

        $dateFrom = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $request->date_from);
        $dateTo = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $request->date_to);
        $days_taken = $dateFrom->diffInDays($dateTo)+1;

        if($request->leave_id == 1){
            if($days_taken > auth()->user()->total_annual){
                return redirect()->route('admin.leaverequest.create')->with('error', 'Leave exceed');
            }
        }
        else{
            return redirect()->route('admin.leaverequest.index')
            ->with('success', 'Leave Application Submitted');
        }

        Application::create([
            'user_id'=>auth()->user()->id,
            'leave_id'=>$request->leave_id,
            'date_from'=>$request->date_from,
            'date_to'=>$request->date_to,
            'days_taken'=> $dateFrom->diffInDays($dateTo)+1,
        ]);
        return redirect()->route('admin.leaverequest.index')
            ->with('success', 'Leave Application Submitted');
    }
```

This is the function for approve/rejecting the leave request.

```
 public function approval(Request $request, $id){
    
            $leaverequest = Application::find($id);
            
            if($leaverequest->status = $request->approve){
                
                $leaverequest->save();
                return redirect()->back();
            }
            elseif($leaverequest->status = $request->reject){
                $leaverequest->save();
                return redirect()->back();
            }
           
        }
```

This function is for the calculation to deduct the total leave everytime if the leave request is approved. If not, the total leave will stay as it is.

```
    public function leaveBalance(Request $request, $id){
    
                $leaverequest = Application::all();
                $days_taken = $request->days_taken;
                $annual_balance = User::find($id);
                
                if($request->status == 1){
                    $annual_balance->total_annual = $annual_balance->total_annual - $days_taken;
                    $annual_balance->save();
                    return redirect()->route('home');
                }
                
            }
```

The other functions seems to function well except for the leaveBalance function. I've tried using this code but also didn't work.

```
auth()->user()->total_annual = auth()->user(->total_annual - $days_taken;
auth()->user()->save();
```

Comment: Please share more details. What's the exact problem with the given code? What have you tried to resolve the problem?

Comment: You're opening yourself up for problems in my opinion - if you have a separate table that stores each period of leave and contains the number of days within each period, there's no real need to store the total in another table. When you need the total, just get it from the `leave` table. That will prevent any problems where the two go out of sync.

Comment: The total leave column is not updated when I have minus it with the days taken

Comment: Please share more details. What have you tried to resolve the problem?

Comment: I've updated by question.

Comment: Please share your attempts to resolve the problem. Why not use var_dump to check which parts are executed, and which are not? Why not start XDebug to properly debug the request? Also, "didn't work" is a pretty broad description.  Also, there are good reaons to put such calculations in a seperate service, such that this is testable through PHPUnit or other tools

Comment: I got your point, thank you for enlighten about this. Need to learn and explore about this

Answer (score 0):

First of code looks fine , but if you getting error or not updating record then i suggests to debug your code first that all variables have values like $annual_balance = User::find($id); did you get data in this? and if you get all things then try to store $annual_balance->total_annual in one variable and then subtract code from variable.

```
       function leaveBalance(Request $request, $id){

        $leaverequest = Application::all();
        $days_taken = $request->days_taken;
        $annual_balance = User::find($id);
        
        if($request->status == 1){
            $total_annual = $annual_balance->total_annual;
            $annual_balance->total_annual = $total_annual - $days_taken;
            $annual_balance->save();

            return redirect()->route('home');
        }
        
    }
```

// Or you can try using DB if above not work don't forget to add Use DB on top of Controller.

```
             $affected = DB::table('users')
          ->where('id', $id)
          ->update(['total_annual' => $total_annual]);
```

Comment: I've tried with both but still the total leave is not updated

Comment: Strange , did you debug the code? Or is it possible to print update query in condition and then check it may be some small issue which you missed

Comment: also i found auth()->user()->total_annual = auth()->user(->total_annual - $days_taken; that this is bug line   it must be auth()->user()->total_annual = auth()->user()->total_annual - $days_taken;

Answer (score 0):

You could also try this

I would say return a single total_annual (total_annual refers to the total leave field in the users table) for a certain user from the user table and note the keyword value() in the query which indicates one value.

`$annual_balance` variable store a total annual leave and `$days_taken` store the number of leave days taken and do some calculation as below to set the total annual which is the remaining total annual leave after days taken
`$annual_balance->total_annual = $annual_balance - $days_taken;`

```
public function leaveBalance(Request $request, $id){

    $days_taken = $request->days_taken;
    $annual_balance = User::where('user_id', $id)->select('total_annual')->value('total_annual');
            
    if($request->status == 1)
    {
       $annual_balance->total_annual = $annual_balance - $days_taken;
       $annual_balance->save();
       return redirect()->route('home');
    }    
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it.